# Decode chunked JSON with AKKA Stream

Tags: json, scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a `Source[ByteString, _]` from an input file with 3 rows like this (in reality the input is a TCP socket with a continuos stream):

```
{"a":[2
33]
}
```

Now the problem is that I want to parse this into a `Source[ChangeMessage,_]`, however the only examples I have found deals with when there is a whole JSON message for every row not when each JSON message can be fragmented over multiple rows.

One example I found is this [this](https://github.com/knutwalker/akka-stream-json) library, however it expects `}` or `,` as last character, that is one JSON per row. The example below shows this setup.

```
"My decoder" should "decode chunked json" in {
    implicit val sys = ActorSystem("test")
    implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()
    val file = Paths.get("chunked_json_stream.json")
    val data = FileIO.fromPath(file)
    .via(CirceStreamSupport.decode[ChangeMessage])
    .runWith(TestSink.probe[ChangeMessage])
    .request(1)
    .expectComplete()
  }
```

Another alternative would be to use a fold and balance `}` and only emit when a whole JSON is completed. The problem with this is that the fold operator only emits when the stream completes and since this is a continuous stream I can not use it here.

> My question is: What is the fastest way to parse chunked JSON streams
>   in AKKA Stream and are there any available software that already does
>   this? If possible I would like to use [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documentation of [knutwalker/akka-stream-json](https://github.com/knutwalker/akka-stream-json) says:

> This flow even supports parsing multiple json documents in whatever fragmentation they may arrive, which is great for consuming stream/sse based APIs.

In your case all you need to do is to just delimit the incoming ByteStrings:

```
"My decoder" should "decode chunked json" in {
    implicit val sys = ActorSystem("test")
    implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()
    val file = Paths.get("chunked_json_stream.json")

    val sourceUnderTest =
      FileIO.fromPath(file)
        .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 8192, allowTruncation = true))
        .via(CirceStreamSupport.decode[ChangeMessage])

    sourceUnderTest
      .runWith(TestSink.probe[ChangeMessage])
      .request(1)
      .expectNext(ChangeMessage(List(233)))
      .expectComplete()
}
```

That's because when reading from file, ByteString elements contain multiple lines and therefore Circe is not able to parse malformed jsons. When you delimit by new line, each element in the stream is a separate line and therefore Circe is able to parse it using the aformentioned feature.

Comment: Acctually I got it working by using CirceStreamSupport without any JsonFraming?

Comment: @user3139545 Thanks for your remark. I clarified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any Scala libraries which support stream-based parsing of JSON. It *seems* to me that some support for this is available in Google Gson, but I'm not entirely sure it can properly handle "broken" input.

What you can do, however, is to collect JSON documents in a streaming fashion, similarly to what [`Framing.delimiter`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Framing$.html#delimiter(delimiter:akka.util.ByteString,maximumFrameLength:Int,allowTruncation:Boolean):akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.util.ByteString,akka.util.ByteString,akka.NotUsed]) does. This is very similar to the alternative you have mentioned, but it is not using `fold()`; if you do go this way, you would probably need to mimic what `Framing.delimiter` does but instead of looking for a single delimiter, you will need to balance curly braces (and optionally brackets, if top-level arrays are possible), buffering the intermediate data, until the entire document comes through, which you would emit as a single chunk suitable for parsing.

Just as a side note, an appropriate interface for a streaming JSON parser suitable to be used in Akka Streams could look like this:

```
trait Parser {
  def update(data: Array[Byte])  // or String
  def pull(): Option[Either[Error, JsonEvent]]
}
```

where `pull()` returns `None` if it can't read anymore but there are no actual syntactic errors in the incoming document, and `JsonEvent` is some standard structure for describing events of streaming parsers (i.e. a sealed trait with subclasses like `BeginObject`, `BeginArray`, `EndObject`, `EndArray`, `String`, etc.). If you find such a library or create one, you can use it to parse data coming from an Akka stream of `ByteString`s.